# UnknownHostExcetpion on Linux

Tags: java, ubuntu-13.10, unknown-host

I'm getting UnknownHostException: www.google.com in method

```
public static String getSource(String url) throws IOException {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4;"
                    + " en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) "
                    + "Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        a.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    return a.toString();
}
```

I have this problem on Ubuntu 13.10 but on Windows 7 everything is working fine.

Comment: may be your firewall is blocking the connection.Also check your proxy.

Comment: What happens when you call a `ping www.google.com` from the command line?

Comment: ping: unknown host www.google.com

Comment: make sure you are connected to internet. Try to ping url/locations other than google too.

Comment: Well, that is the answer... If ping does not work, it's because you either have no dns configured or any other networking problem. You should check your network configuration first...